# Copy a controller class instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, erb

I want to write a simple erb template generator to parse stored erb templates from the views using `Generator` module. I call the `Generator` from the rails controller to generate it's singleton instances and pass it the `WallController` by `self` pointer.

```rb
require 'generator'

class WallController < ApplicationController
  def index
    header = File.read 'app/views/application-header.html'.freeze
    @instances = {header: header}
    # Load view generators
    Generator.generate_instances self
  end 
end
```

The first thing `Generator.generate_instances` actually attempts to do is to copy the `WallController` instance variables (hence the self pointer) to perform correct parsing of the erb templates. Then it generates methods returning erb resulted text.

```rb
require 'erb'

module Generator
  def self.generate_instances environment
    # Mimic class environment
    if environment.superclass == ApplicationController
      environment.instance_variables.each do |v| 
        puts "Copy instance variable '#{v}' from #{environment.name} to #{self.name}"
        value = environment.instance_variable_get(v)
        self.send :instance_variable_set, v, value
      end 
    end 
    # Parse the ERB templates
    templates = @instances
    return 0 if !templates.is_a?(Hash) or templates.empty? 
    templates.keys.each.with_index do |key, index|
      define_singleton_method key do
        ERB.new(templates.values[index]).result
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```

Usage of `Generator` interface will look like this:

```
<%=== Generator.header %>
```

I am new to rails but I have found out that rails controller's included files are limited to a single static structure. I didn't manage either to overwrite `class Object` or `class Class` singleton methods which could be helpful.

However, after running the above example the instance variables of `WallController` return the `WallController` class address in stead of values defined by `WallController.index`.

```
undefined method `empty?' for #<WallController:0x000000000a1f90>
```

Is there a correct way to distribute a rails controller instance variables among other controllers? If not, why are regular instance copy not working?

If I had to write it in ruby, that would be easy:

```
module Y
  def self.generate_environment environment
    environment.instance_variables.each do |v| 
      puts "Copy #{v} from #{environment.name} to #{self.name}"
      value = environment.instance_variable_get v
      self.instance_variable_set(v, value)
    end if environment.class == Class
        
    puts "Retrived string: #{@hello}"
  end 
end

class X
  def self.index
    @hello = 'Hello, World!'
    Y.generate_environment self
  end 
end

X.index
```

Comment: You're passing an instance of `WallController` to `Generator.generate_instances` as `environment`, then you check if that instance is `Class` with `environment == Class`. The `environment == Class` will always fail so you end up not copying any instance variables.

Comment: Ow, thank you. Bad typo. I fixed that in the question now.

Comment: You're still passing `self`, which is an instance, then checking if `env.class == Class`, which is false as `self` is a `WallController`

Comment: `WallController.class == class`, this is true.

Comment: However, I change it to `environment.superclass == ApplicationController` to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may be solved with [viewcomponent](https://viewcomponent.org/), which allows for standard ruby code for the view controller. Also solves the problem of dividing the view code to smaller reusable components in reasonable speed.

To use the viewcomponent gem first include it to your Gemfile.

```rb
gem 'view_component', require: 'view_component/engine'
```

After updating your gems with `bundle install`, you will also need to restart your server if it's running, to apply the new gem.

Then generating the component is similar in usage to other rails generators. The first argument is a component name and the second is a component argument.

```sh
rails generate component Header site_id
```

Now I focus on files generated in `app/component` directory, view and controller code. This will simply be the controller to create the header snippet of the view.

Inside of `app/component/header_component.rb` can be encapsulated all the code from `WallController` related to the header view.

```rb
class HeaderComponent < ViewComponent::Base
  def initialize(site_id:)
    puts "Rendering header component for site: #{site_id}"
    # Load site elements
    @site = Site.find site_id
    @menu_items = []
    Site.all.each.with_index do |site, index|
      @menu_items.push site.title => site.link
    end 
  end
end
```

Similarly, put all the header view erb code to the `app/component/header.html.erb`.

The finished component can be generated from the view using rails render:

```rb
  <%= render HeaderComponent.new(site_id: 1) %>
```